# Evaluate the integral $\iiint\limits_E x^2 \,\, \mathrm{d}V$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume, spherical-coordinates

Where E is the region bounded by the xz-plane and the hemispheres $y=\sqrt{9-x^2-z^2}$ and $y=\sqrt{16-x^2-z^2}$.

---

*This is an exercise from my professor guide.*

What I tried so far:

These exercise is obviously easier using spherical coordinates, with that in mind I've come up with the following limits:

$
3 \le \rho \le 4 \\
0 \le \phi \le \pi \\
0 \le \theta\ \le \pi
$

That is, the sphere cap formed by the 2 semi-spheres, more or less the volume described between the 2 surfaces in the image:

[image: Sphere cap]

With the limits already established, I constructed the following integral:

$\int_0^\pi \int_0^\pi \int_3^4 \, \cos^2{(\theta)} \sin^3{(\phi)} \, \rho^4 \,\, \mathrm{d}\rho \, \mathrm{d}\phi \, \mathrm{d}\theta$
$= \frac{1562}{15}\pi$

However, the solution tha appears in the guide says that the result is:

$\frac{3124}{15}\pi$

---

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I checked the exercise twice and I get the correct result IF I set the limits of $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, but that is the whole spherical surface not just the half described by the exercise.

Best regards,
Daniel Rivas.

Comment: it seems that you are correct.

Comment: Your result is correct. It seems the guide computed the value for the full spherical shell.

Comment: That's nice to hear you know!? I have been smashing my head against the wall for some time now... I thought I was missing something.

Comment: @DanielRS: See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You did not get the right $\theta$! Here is what it should be

> $$ 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi $$

since the region in the $xz$-plane is an annulus.

Comment: Yeah, I get the right result with those limits, however could you provide a more in-depth explanation? What's special about the annulus?

Comment: @DanielRS: Just imagine the $xz$-plane cutting the two spheres. What's the resulting region in the $xz$-plane is going to be? Keeping in mind you want to find the volume between the two spheres.

Comment: A ring-like shape is formed, but why is this shape different from anything else? It would be $2\pi$ if I wanted the whole shell volume right? Not just the half.

Comment: @DanielRS: Do you mean the whole volume between the two spheres? So in this case $\phi$ comes in the play.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Yeah, π for half the volume between the 2 spheres, and 2π for the whole volume between them.

Comment: (I was wrong about $\phi$). I think the limits in the integral are correct, since the region only includes the part of the region between the spheres which is to the right of the xz-plane.